# Show DialogFragment from another Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, dialogfragment

I have managed to show DialogFragment from an Activity. But how to achieve this from Fragment?

My DialogFragment look like this:

```java
package com.tes

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{

    public AlertDialogFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new AlertDialogFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Test title");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // on success
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }
}
```

I have a main activity which show TestFragment like this:

```java
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,  fragment)
                .commit();
```

and in my TestFragment I want to show my dialog:

```java
 AlertDialogFragment newFragment = AlertDialogFragment
                .newInstance();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        newFragment.show(fm, "dialogs");
```

But it doesn't work. Wjen I tap Back button, right before app is closed I see that Dialog is present. So it looks like it is shown below my fragment, or just put somehow on backStack. I don't know.

I have tried to show DialogFragment from Fragment or from MainActivity by sending event via Listener from TestFragment to MainActivity which listens to Listener.

Comment: post your TestFragment;

Comment: I used the onStart() method which fires upon creation of the fragment. Then I had created a background thread to run the dialog until the data is loaded in my case.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I have tested in on a few Fragments like Fragment, PreferenceFragment etc. It doesn't work even on a basic Fragment made by default snippet in Android Studio